# I got an error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got an error "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'TIMEZONE'".

View

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EventListing.Models.EventInfo>" %>               
        <%= Html.DropDownList("TIMEZONE", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TIMEZONE"], "Select Timezone")%>
```

Controller

```
ViewData["TIMEZONE"] = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value");
return View();
```

Model Page

```
public static IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> getTIMEZOMES
        {
            get
            {
                Dbhelper DbHelper = new Dbhelper();
                IList<KeyValuePair<String, String>> Timezone = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();
                DbCommand cmd = DbHelper.GetSqlStringCommond("SELECT * FROM TMP_TIMEZONES");
                DbDataReader Datareader = DbHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
                while (Datareader.Read())
                {
                    Timezone.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>(Datareader["ABBR"].ToString(), Datareader["NAME"].ToString()));
                }

                return Timezone;
            }
        }
```

Plz Give the solution.

Comment: That's a very bad property nme.  It should be called `TimeZones`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason could be, In the controller, you may not be getting the data into the `ViewData["TimeZone"]`. Try to debug it and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use the same property for binding the dropdownlist to and the selectlist. They should be distinct. The first argument must represent a scalar property which will be used as name of the generated select. The second argument must be the list:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedTimeZone", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TIMEZONE"], 
    "Select Timezone"
) %>
```

This will use the collection contained in `ViewData["TIMEZONE"]` to generate the select like this:

```
<select name="SelectedTimeZone">
    <option value="1">zone 1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

When the form is submitted you will look for the `SelectedTimeZone` property in the request to fetch the corresponding selected value.

This being said I notice that your view is strongly typed to some model:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EventListing.Models.EventInfo>"
```

but you aren't passing any model when returning this view:

```
ViewData["TIMEZONE"] = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value");
return View(); // <!-- where is the Model???
```

So what I would recommend you is to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public SelectList TimeZones { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTimeZone { get; set; }

    // ... include some other properties that might be
    // needed by this view
}
```

and then have your controller action populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        TimeZones = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view use a strongly typed DropDownListFor helper:

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EventListing.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedTimeZone, 
    Model.TimeZones, 
    "Select Timezone"
) %>
```

Comment: @sathishkumar, if this post helped you solve the problem you should consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov : I got an error while submit "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: @sathishkumar, on which line you get this error? Does this happen inside the controller action you are posting to?

Comment: On View page <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedTimeZone, 
    Model.TimeZones, 
    "Select Timezone"
) %>

Comment: @sathishkumar, inside your POST action you need to populate the TimeZones property on your view model the same way you did in the GET action. Remember that the HTTP protocol is stateless and only the selected value is sent to the server when you submit the form. If you intend to show the same view from your POST action you should absolutely make sure that the TimeZones property of your view model is initialized.

Comment: Actually i'm new to this technology. Can u show the sample, i don't have much knowlodge.

Comment: @sathishkumar, your POST action now takes `MyViewModel` as argument. Right? Inside you simply write `model.TimeZones = new SelectList(EventModel.getTIMEZOMES, "Key", "Value"); return View(model);`, the same way you did in the GET action.

Comment: Sorry for disturb again : in Model Class Contains public SelectList TimeZones { get; set; }
        public string SelectedTimeZone { get; set; } where can i set the value

Comment: @sathishkumar, inside the POST controller action to which you are submitting the form. I would really suggest you going through the getting started tutorials on the ASP.NET MVC site: http://asp.net/mvc to gather some deeper understanding of how the framework works.

Comment: In My Post Method i submitted all the values but it's showing error,       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(EventInfo EventInfo)
        {
                EventModel.Create(EventInfo);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                return View();
        }